# How to add inputed string into a 2D array without overwriting preivous entry?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm making a simple password vault that's a 2d array [20][3]. I can input one row then put it in the array, but when I enter the second entry, it overwrites the previous entry.

I have attempted adding a second for loop so it will drop to the next row after adding a new entry.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class passSimple 
{
static char[][] conversionTable = new char[27][2];
static String[][] passVault = new String[20][3];
static String password = "";
static String username = "";
static String website = "";

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    getMorePass();
}

public static void getMorePass()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What website is this for? (No space and all capitals): ");
    website = input.next();

    System.out.println("Whats your username? (No space and all capitals): ");
    username = input.next();

    System.out.println("Whats your password? (No space and all capitals): ");
    password = input.next();

    System.out.println("Would you like to add another password? ");
    String check = input.next();

    AddPassword(password, username, website);
    System.out.println();

    if(check.compareTo("YES") == 0)
    {
        getMorePass();
    }
    else;
}

public static void addPassword(String password, String website, String username)
{
    //SavePassword

    for (int x = 0; x < passVault.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < passVault.length;y++)
        {
        passVault[x][y] = username;
        passVault[x][y] = website;
        passVault[x][y] = password;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(passVault[1]));
}
```

}

I expect the output to be "

```
[website2, username2, password2]


[website1, username1, password1]
```

but it instead replaces `[website1, username1, password1]` with `[website2, username2, password2]`

Comment: This is because you have an error in your logic. You should apply [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), which should allow you to find the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We do not see what type `passVault` is for example.

Comment: When you call AddPassword, you complete the entire passVault with the same value

Comment: Also, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: method names are written in camelCase, meaning they start with lowercase.

Comment: You wouldn't need the nested loops if you had used a `List<String[]>` or even proper objects for this. You actually start looping at index 0 but only add values to the array once in every call of `addPassword` (method names should start in lower case).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you

```
public static void addPassword(String password, String website, String username){
   for (int x = 0; x < passVault.length; x++){          
      if(passVault[x][0]==null && passVault[x][0]==null && passVault[x][0]==null){
         //put only if there are no value
         passVault[x][0] = username;
         passVault[x][1] = website;
         passVault[x][2] = password;
         break;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(passVault[1]));
}
```

But it could be more simplier with List